# Finding outlier point in set of points, by distance, using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, density, spatial-outliers

I need to identify and eliminate the outlier points in a set of points, as depicted below. It seems a simple task, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

I suspect that the proper way to go is through a density analysis. But I cannot figure out.

I am using QGIS.

[image: OUTLIERS VISUALIZATION]

Comment: There are some **cluster analysis** tools that can come handy. I suggest you to edit the question with the technology you are using.

Comment: Done! Thanks. I am using QGIS. As my data set has 500K point grouped in 5,000 sets, I will need to resolve this problem in Python, as I will have to replicate this 5,000 times, for each set of points.

Comment: Sketch for a minimal solution: (1) triangulate the point cloud; (2) calculate the average distance A and the corresponding standart derivation S from all triangle edges.  (3) remove egdes larger than A+S*m, while m is a skalar like (1.5, 2,...) see [Normal distribution, standart derivation and coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage), (4) remove points not connected to main group

Comment: @huckfinn your solutions sounds good. As an alternative to the "abnormal distance" that you suggest, I was thinking that an "abnormal density" may even be more simple: outlier points will always be in a cell with a density of 1 or 2.

Comment: For a simple cell based approach you could work with [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Quadtrees going into the direction of @JGH in terms of spatial clustering. Please refer to [GIS.SE:5394](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/incremental-spatial-clustering-algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer straight from ROSSI, Richard E., MULLA, David J., JOURNEL, Andre G. and FRANZ, Eldon H., 1992. Geostatistical tools for modeling and interpreting ecological spatial dependence. *Ecological Monographs*. 1 February 1992. Vol. 62, no. 2, p. 277–314. DOI 10.2307/2937096. Available (free) from: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2307/2937096/pdf

> Outliers can be identified through a variety of means.
>   One technique was described earlier: **h-scattergram**
>   values that plot very far from the 45° line are likely
>   outlier candidates. With this method it is incumbent
>   on the researcher to investigate these possible outliers.
>   For example, does the suspected outlier occur in an
>   area of generally small or large values? Could the unusual value be an incorrectly coded datum? Is the suspected outlier's presence due to an environmental or
>   organism anomaly? Only after good ecological judgment should an outlier be removed prior to variogram
>   analysis. This process can be tedious for large, outlier-laden data sets, but it is perhaps the only legitimate
>   means for outlier identification and removal. With so
>   few rating categories in the present data, outliers will
>   be particularly difficult to explicitly identify.
>
> Many other, more automatic, outlier identification
>   techniques have been proposed. Dowd (1984) can be
>   consulted for reviews of many of the more popular-
>   often called "resistant"- **variogram methods**, i.e., variograms that are resistant to the outliers' effects. Huber
>   (1964, 1972) provides an excellent statistical examination of outlier-resistant estimation. Some of the more
>   popular resistant variogram techniques are: the **medium absolute deviation estimator** (Dowd 1984, Journel 1984a), **generalized distance measures** (Journel
>   1989), **median polish** (Cressie 1984, 1986), the **Cressie-
>   Hawkins estimator** (Cressie and Hawkins 1980), and
>   **Omre's estimator** (Omre 1984).

Here is a more recent paper with other algorithms that detect spatial outliers by multi-iterations :

LU, C.-T., CHEN, D. and KOU, Y., 2003. Algorithms for spatial outlier detection. In: *Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on Data Mining (ICDM’03)*. IEEE Comput. Soc. 2003. p. 597–600. ISBN 978-0-7695-1978-4. Available from: http://europa.nvc.cs.vt.edu/~ctlu/Publication/1998-2006/ICDM-2003-P.pdf